# Importance of using getch() inside a for-loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, getch

I just wanted to ask what the importance of using `getch()` is, especially in this array/for-loop example that our professor showed us:

```
int i;
char pw[7], ch;

printf ("\npw: ");

for (i=0; i<7; i++) {
    ch = getch();
    pw[i] = ch;
    printf ("%c", ch);
}
```

I tried removing the `ch = getch()` line and what happened when I ran the program was that the loop went on forever.

Why does that happen?

I only understand that `getch()` is used at the end of a program to not show a character on the screen (from online definitions).

Comment: "the loop when on for forever." Are you sure? That loop should terminate after 7 iterations regardless of whether the `getch` is there or not.

Comment: when i compile and run it, the program never stops;; maybe a glitch in dev-c++??? @kaylum

Comment: I doubt very much that the compiler has a bug with such a simple program. What exactly do you see when the program is run without the `getch` line? Anything get printed? (It would mean `ch` is uninitialised and thus the program technically invokes Undefined Behaviour but it still shouldn't result in the behaviour that you are claiming).

Comment: what gets printed repeatedly is "pw:" and "incorrect pw" ("incorret pw" is my else condition for the if-else that comes after this array/for-loop) @kaylum

Comment: This is not a complete program. Nobody has any idea what happens in the parts you omitted. Besides, if you want to kniw what `getch` does, why not type `getch` in your favourite search engine?

Comment: @fujisaki You are not making much sense. 1. You are referring to code that you haven't shown us and that is really not helpful. 2. How does what you described equate to "the loop went on forever"? You just said it executes code after the loop! How can it execute code after the loop if the loop "went on forever"?

Comment: Please post an [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getch() reads a character from the keyboard without echoing it.

so your program is reading a character from the keybord (user input). and storing it in ch variable, then saving it in the string array pw[], at the end echoing it using printf("%c");

by removing `ch = getch();`.  your program stops reading from keyboard. and fills the pw[] with the same value of (uninitialized ) ch exactly 7 times, and then exit loop.

according to what you posted, you program hangs elsewhere, where you are testing the validity of the password.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out getch line it runs and ends, it does not loop forever, you must have removed more to change it into a loop forever. To answer your initial question [getch] gets a char and then the program displays it, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

`Getch()` - Reads a single character from `STDIN`, if none exists, waits for it!

In your example, `Getch()` plays a central role, reading the user input (given 7 characters).

if you remove this statement, not only you leave `int ch` uninitialized (with no valid value),
but the loop wont wait for anything (as `getch()` won't wait).

Sometimes, especially when learning `c++`, running a simple program from Visual Studio (or whatever IDE you use)...
running the program is very short, and you cant see the output!
so one adds `getch();` at the end, just to tell the program to wait for any character, or put differently, leave the window open and wait for my key-press.